# Macbook Pro mid-2014 (High Sierra) runs very hot

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra

My 5-ish year old Macbook Pro Retina running High Sierra runs very hot. I know the battery needs replacing, but I'm trying to work out if it makes sense to do this or if my Macbook is on the way out and I need a new laptop. The EtreCheck report is here: https://pastebin.com/VRaKknrF

The CPU temperature routinely runs above 65, and goes up to 75-80.

I'd be so grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

80 Celsius is well within normal CPU temperature for an MBP.

If it is working too hard, then I would look at all those third-party software listed in the EtreCheck report, and make sure they are necessary and up-to-date. If not, uninstall them.

I would definitely get rid of the Western Digital helper software. Some versions caused major problems with some OS versions.
Do you need VideoGuard? Flash? Silverlight? (MS killed that years ago.)
Some versions of Chrome have been known to install Google software update agents that run wild with CPU resources.
You're also running some fan control program: might that be limiting the cooling? Try it without.
You've got Monolingual from 2014. Loads of other stuff that I have no idea what it is. 'Freedom' doesn't seem to have been updated by the developer since 2014.

Your Mac might also be slow because you're running out of disk storage.

I have a 2014 MBP, and just got a new battery from Apple, and it runs like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I recently opened up my macbook and used a can of air and blow out all the crap on the fans and all the other parts. Hasn't been running hot. Also update your OS and browser(s) like Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

I have a 2012 macbook pro, I always found it tended to run too hot for my liking (I use my laptop on my lap and at higher temperatures it is uncomfortable). I think the issue is the system default fan control errs on the side of quietness.

I have been using fan control tools for a while to help with this. More recently I  switched to one called [TG Pro](https://www.tunabellysoftware.com/tgpro/) and configured the auto boost thresholds so that the fans kick in earlier than they would if the system was allowed to control the fans.

My macbook now runs considerably less hot most of the time (ofc when it is very busy it is still going to get hot).